# Proper clipboard format for Windows 10 Start Menu element

Tags: vb.net, windows, com

I'm implementing an IDropTarget COM interface which allow any OLE application to drag it's data over my application. However, it fails when I drop a menu item  from Windows 10 Start Menu.

The code works fine with folders and files from the desktop or Windows Explorer, but fails when it comes from the Start Menu.

The code fails in iDataObject::QueryGetData using CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST clipboard format.

Someone knows what is the proper clipboard format used by a Start Menu item in Windows 10? Apparently I could use IDataObject::EnumFormatEtc but can not find any example.

Here is the relevant code:

```
_format = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST)

Public Function DragDrop1(ByVal pDataObj As System.IntPtr, ByVal grfKeyState As Integer, ByVal pt As ShellCOM._POINT, ByRef pdwEffect As Integer) As Integer Implements ShellCOM.IDropTarget.DragDrop

        Dim DataObj As ShellCOM.IDataObject
        DataObj = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(pDataObj, GetType(ShellCOM.IDataObject))

        If DataObj IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim format As New FORMATETC
            Dim medium As New STGMEDIUM

            format.cfFormat = _format
            format.ptd = 0
            format.dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT
            format.lindex = 0
            format.Tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL

            If DataObj.QueryGetData(format) = S_OK Then      <----- code fail here, what is the correct format of an element from Windows 10 Start Menu?
                 ' ....
                 ' ....
            End If
        End If

    Return S_OK
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. [IDataObject::QueryGetData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) website indicates that currently only -1 is supported for lindex member. So now my app can get the menu item paths.

```
format.lindex = -1
```